How to use @RequestParam array for multiple data types?
I'm building a Spring Boot Controller with a @RequestParam array.
The thing is, the input will be a mix of Image upload (new  image) and String (Existing image's id) in the request's body as FormData.
If, it is a new image, I have to upload the image and get it's id.
If it is an existing image, I simply use the same id from the input.
In the controller, I tried using
@RequestParam Object[] images

and
if (images[i] instanceof String) {
// Existing Image
} else if (images[i] instanceof MultipartFile) {
// New Image
}

This works if all the items are images or all the items or string.
But, if it is a mixture of both, the Controller captures only the MultipartFile
When I check on the Network tab (Browser), all the String and Files are uploaded fine.
Can anyone help me with capturing the diferent types?

Awesome question Bro,
You're right. Your method just received all files or all strings because the logic on resolveName method in org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver. Parameter values will be ignored if there are multipart files:
Object arg = null;
MultipartRequest multipartRequest = request.getNativeRequest(MultipartRequest.class);
if (multipartRequest != null) {
    List<MultipartFile> files = multipartRequest.getFiles(name);
    if (!files.isEmpty()) {
        arg = (files.size() == 1 ? files.get(0) : files);
    }
}
if (arg == null) {
    String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(name);
    if (paramValues != null) {
        arg = (paramValues.length == 1 ? paramValues[0] : paramValues);
    }
}
return arg;

I have just found out solution after spent time on this article A Custom Data Binder in Spring MVC and some interesting Spring class.
First of all, we create marking annotation @MixMultipartFileAndString
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface MixMultipartFileAndString {
}

Next, we create a customized HandlerMethodArgumentResolver which accept all multipart files and parameter string:

public class MixMultipartFileAndStringArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(MixMultipartFileAndString.class) != null;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param methodParameter the method parameter to resolve. This parameter must
     * have previously been passed to {@link #supportsParameter} which must
     * have returned {@code true}.
     * @param mavContainer the ModelAndViewContainer for the current request
     * @param request the current request
     * @param binderFactory a factory for creating {@link WebDataBinder} instances
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     * @see org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver#resolveName(String, MethodParameter, NativeWebRequest)
     */
    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest request, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = request.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
        String name = methodParameter.getParameterName();
        if (servletRequest != null) {
            Object mpArg = MultipartResolutionDelegate.resolveMultipartArgument(name, methodParameter, servletRequest);
            if (mpArg != MultipartResolutionDelegate.UNRESOLVABLE) {
                return mpArg;
            }
        }

        List<Object> arg = new ArrayList<>();
        MultipartRequest multipartRequest = request.getNativeRequest(MultipartRequest.class);
        if (multipartRequest != null) {
            List<MultipartFile> files = multipartRequest.getFiles(name);
            if (!files.isEmpty()) {
                arg.addAll(files);
            }
        }

        String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(name);
        if (paramValues != null) {
            Collections.addAll(arg, paramValues);
        }
        return arg;
    }
}

And then, we have to register:
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   @Override
   public void addArgumentResolvers(
           List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
      argumentResolvers.add( new MixMultipartFileAndStringArgumentResolver());
   }
}

Finally, use it in our controller:
@PostMapping("/api")
public void uploadOrGetImages(@MixMultipartFileAndString List<Object> images) {
    for (Object object: images) {
        if (object instanceof MultipartFile) {}
        if (object instanceof String) {}
    }
}


Hope helps.

@RequestParam is used to handle simple data types and probably can't handle complex types that you need, image and string in your case.
You can try using @RequestPart instead of @RequestParam.
@RequestPart("images") Object[] images

if (images[i] instanceof String) {
    // Existing Image
} else if (images[i] instanceof MultipartFile) {
    // New Image
}

This will allow you to handle multiple type of data received from the client.

Tried it but received this exception.
HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported
